# git repo corrupted, unable to status with: "BUG: fsmonitor.c:21: fsmonitor_dirty has more entries than the index"

Tags: git, corruption

First indication of issue:

```bash
❯ git rebase -r master
BUG: fsmonitor.c:21: fsmonitor_dirty has more entries than the index (179457 > 1040)
zsh: abort      git rebase -r master
```

Got "stuck" in this state, not sure how to recover or repro:

```bash
❯ git status
BUG: fsmonitor.c:21: fsmonitor_dirty has more entries than the index (179457 > 1040)
error: git died of signal 6

❯ git log  # works

❯ git diff head~
error: git died of signal 6
BUG: fsmonitor.c:21: fsmonitor_dirty has more entries than the index (179457 > 1040)

❯ git diff head~..head~~  # works

❯ git checkout head
BUG: fsmonitor.c:21: fsmonitor_dirty has more entries than the index (179457 > 1040)
zsh: abort      git checkout head
```

Comment: This indicates a bug in Git (any of the `BUG` messages mean that). As a temporary workaround, consider disabling the file system monitor. If your clean-up-and-reset gets around it, that's also usable. (To disable it, see your `git config` documentation; look for `core.fsmonitor`.)

Comment: I'd prefer keeping it on b/c I'm in a large repo. I submitted a `git bugreport` to the mailing list, though I don't know if they can repro. As always, such is the risk in using new features!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out git's index got corrupted during the rebase.

From: https://git.seveas.net/repairing-and-recovering-broken-git-repositories.html

```bash
mkdir .git/my_backup
mv .git/sharedindex.* .git/my_backup
mv .git/index .git/my_backup
git reset --mixed  # rebuild index
```

**updates**:

likely related git mailing list threads:

- https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqbkhv6dw3.fsf@gitster.g/T/#m3a0ae8d18c63d8372a3f3e846f0c358857e660b5
- https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqbkhv6dw3.fsf@gitster.g/T/#m13a5ad383f040bb3a6be7641bd04aa20424a274c

Suspected culprit is setting config `core.splitIndex` along with `core.fsmonitor` (and/or possibly `feature.manyFiles`).

Though it may have been fixed in 2.4.1: https://github.com/git/git/commit/3704fed5eae8ca2fa20bcf6adb277ee83b012ce0